# Define a function that takes an array as an argument and return a new array modified according to the instructions passed in as a block in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, yield

I’m having trouble storing the return value from each block invocation in a new array.

> Specs:

```
describe "new_map" do
  it "should not call map or map!" do
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    a.stub(:map) { '' }
    a.stub(:map!) { '' }

    expect( new_map(a) { |i| i + 1 } ).to eq([2, 3, 4])
  end

  it "should map any object" do
    a = [1, "two", :three]
    expect( new_map(a) { |i| i.class } ).to eq([Fixnum, String, Symbol])
  end
end
```

> My code:

```
def new_map(array)
  new_array = []
  each do |item|
    new_array << yield(item)
  end
  new_array
end
```

I think I'm close, but can't seem to store the return value in the 'new_array'.

Answer (score 0):

Use each for old array

```
def new_map(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each do |item|
    new_array << yield(item)
  end
  new_array
end
```

This passed your tests

Comment: I don't know what happened there... I'm guessing I had a typo and when I wrote it here it was right. Thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

```
array.inject([]) do |memo, item|
  memo << yield(item)
end
```